# Json.NET and a collection of objects, where the objects are part of a class hierarchy?

Tags: inheritance, json.net

I have the following situation (for this question):

- A document class
- One document can contain multiple items, of various types

Like this [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program:

```
void Main()
{
    var doc = new Document();
    doc.Items.Add(new ItemA { Name = "Test Name" });
    doc.Items.Add(new ItemB { Value = 42 });

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented).Dump();
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Document>(json).Dump();
}

[JsonObjectAttribute("doc")]
public class Document
{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
}

public abstract class Item { }

public class ItemA : Item
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ItemB : Item
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

This program fails with this exception on the call to `DeserializeObject`:

> **JsonSerializationException**: Could not create an instance of type UserQuery+Item. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'items[0].name', line 4, position 14.

I tried adding the `TypeHandling` property to the `JsonProperty` of `Items`:

```
[JsonProperty("items", TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
```

but this produces this Json:

```
{
  "items": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[UserQuery+Item, LINQPadQuery]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
```

which is not quite what I wanted, as it specifies the type for the list, but not for each item, however I can't seem to figure out *if* and *how* this can be done.

By this I want the following type of Json:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "$type": "UserQuery+ItemA, LINQPadQuery",
      "name": "Test Name"
    },
    {
      "$type": "UserQuery+ItemB, LINQPadQuery",
      "value": 42
    }
  ]
}
```

Do I need to introduce a wrapper object with a simple property of type `Item` with that attribute on instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.  Try using `ItemTypeNameHandling` instead of `TypeNameHandling`:

```
[JsonProperty("items", ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
```